# Cómo agrego otro dominio a mi cpanel sin el formato de subdominios?

Tags: webservice, url, hosting, cpanel, dominio

Recientemente compré un segundo nombre de dominio y ya lo he agregado a mi proveedor de hosting. No obstante después de agregarlo al cpanel (AddDomain) sólo puedo acceder a la página dominioNuevo.dominioPrincipal.dom en lugar del formato deseado dominioNuevo.dom

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu hosting admite multidominios?

Comment: Hola! Gracias por contestar. Sí, los admite

Comment: Entonces lo agregaste mal...como lo hiciste?

Comment: Perdón la demora y gracias de nuevo. 
Lo agregué desde Cpanel en la sección de dominios, lo intenté hacer de dos formas posibles.
1) En dominios adicionales 
2) En dominios >> create new domain 
 2.1) compartiendo public_html
 2.2) sin compartir public_html 
De cualquier manera, el único acceso posible es newDom.mainDom.xyz, cuando intento acceder a la dirección newDom.xyz el navegador me indica que no encuentra la IP

Comment: pero al instalar el wp, donde lo instalaste? porque usualmente tenes las dos opciones al agregar un dominio...

Comment: Lo instalé en el public, si lo enstalo en un subdirectorio /wp entonces podría acceder al otro sitio con normalidad?

Comment: Sera tu hosting no te permite tener mas de un dominio de primer nivel? creo que deberias hablarlo con ellos...

Comment: Es posible... Gracias pori la ayuda gbianchi